# Annoying Keyboard bug, Fatal Exception: IllegalArgumentException parameter must be a descendant of this view

Tags: android, keyboard, android-input-method

I have 2 fragment contained inside an `Activity`, when I open the second `Fragment` the keyboard immediately pops up and asks you to type something in.

There are two ways to close the keyboard.

1. Press back (I have a custom EditText that also closes the Fragment when you press back)
2. Swipe up or down on the second Fragment that opens up and it closes the keyboard and fragment.

The annoying bug which occurs is that when I close the Second Fragment it closes the Fragment and Keyboard but when you get back to the First Fragment the Keyboard pops back up again and if the users swipes anywhere on the screen a Fatal Exception occurs.

Here is my code for how to close the Keyboard on the Second Fragment:

When a user swipes on the `RelativeLayout` inside the Second Fragment this is the code block that gets called:

```
relativeLayout.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        float startY = 0, endY = 0;

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

            switch (event.getAction()){
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    startY = event.getY();
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    endY = event.getY();

                    if(Math.abs(startY - endY) > 200) {
                        onHideSoftKeyboard(editText);
                        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
                    }

                    break;
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

 public void onHideSoftKeyboard(final EditText editText) {
    if (mContextWeakReference.get() != null) {
        final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) mContextWeakReference.get().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }
 }
```

Exception that Occurs for Users:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: parameter must be a descendant of this view
   at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetRectBetweenParentAndChild(ViewGroup.java:5191)
   at android.view.ViewGroup.offsetDescendantRectToMyCoords(ViewGroup.java:5128)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.scrollToRectOrFocus(ViewRootImpl.java:2978)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2647)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2577)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2169)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1180)
   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6563)
   at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
   at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
   at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5835)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)
```

How can I resolve this?